# Selecting a cell of a last searched value from a list of many different values through a function or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Backstory: I am trying to create a system that will  show in a separate field how much oil of different types is left in a tanker. Different types of oil come in an go every day so i cant just use a simple sum or lookup last value.

Here is an example. Left column is weight of oil coming in and right is a numerical index identifying what type of oil it is:

```
Volume Oil type
   22  1
   12  1
   23  1
   24  1
   22  1
   23  2
   23  2
   23  2
   22  2
   23  2
   32  3
   22  3
   23  1
   22  1
   13  2
   31  3
   13  3
   21  2
   23  1
   22  3
   23  3
   12  3
   11  2
```

So for this list i need my function to find a last time oil type 1 entered the tanker and then add up all the values for all previous type 1 oil inserted + last one in order to receive a final volume of oil type 1

Expected result should be as follows:

```
Type 1 total volume : 171
Type 2 total volume : 159
Type 3 total volume : 155
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sum values of a column for regions where values in another column are constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271914/sum-values-of-a-column-for-regions-where-values-in-another-column-are-constant/49272582#49272582).

Comment: this sadly doesnt work since that version is a sum for a specified region and numbers have to be in a row

Comment: I find your narrative unclear. [edit] your question to include expected results.

Comment: just edited. I just need a total sum for specific type.

Comment: What's wrong with sumif? You made this sound a lot more difficult that it is.

Comment: Oh yeah i think you are right ! Trying now, will answer asap

Answer (score 0):

Erm pivottable?

Set your data up as a table with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to create a pivottable associated with the table

Then you can add rows to your heart's content and different types and simply right-click refresh pivot.

[image: Pivot]